# Template Literal Inject Object and Pass to a Function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code where I want to pass an order object to deleteOrder function using template literal.

```
function updateUI() {

    let orderItems = orders.map(function(order){
      return `<li class="order">
      <label>${order.name}</label>
      <p>${order.coffee}</p>
      <button onclick="deleteOrder(\"${order.key}\")">Remove</button>
      </li>`
    })

    ordersList.innerHTML = orderItems.join('')

}
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
function updateUI() {

    let orderItems = orders.map(function(order){
      return `<li class="order">
      <label>${order.name}</label>
      <p>${order.coffee}</p>
      <button onclick="deleteOrder('${order.key}')">Remove</button>
      </li>`
    })

    ordersList.innerHTML = orderItems.join('')

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline handlers are bad practice and difficult to manage, as you're finding out. Also, any way you represent an object in HTML, there's no way to make it so that it's `===` to the original object (so, for example, you couldn't use `includes` to check to see if an array contains that object). Attach the handler properly using Javascript instead so that `order` can be referenced via its closure:

```
let orderItems = orders.map((order) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'order';
  li.innerHTML = `
    <label>${order.name}</label>
    <p>${order.coffee}</p>
    <button>Remove</button>`;
  li.children[2].addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteOrder(order);
  });
  return li;
});
```

If you don't want to use `.children[index]`, if your `li` has only one `button`, you can select it with `querySelector`:

```
li.querySelector('button').addEventListener...
```

Note that this will result in `orderItems` returning an array of *elements* rather than an array of *strings*, so rather than using the result to assign to some `innerHTML`, call `appendChild` on the container to append the `li`. For example:

```
const lis = orderItems(orderArr);
lis.forEach((li) => {
  container.appendChild(li);
});
```

If you want to pass `order.key` to `deleteOrder` instead of passing `order`, then replace

```
deleteOrder(order);
```

with

```
deleteOrder(order.key);
```

Although inline handlers shouldn't be used, the way to do it would be to use double quotes around the whole `onclick` attribute, and single quotes around the `order.key` string, making sure to escape any single or double quotes in `order.key`:

```
const escapedKey = order.key.replace(/['"]/g, '\\$&');
// ...
<button onclick="deleteOrder('${escapedKey}')">Remove</button>
```

But the escaping is ugly and inelegant - attach the handler with Javascript instead.

Comment: Anyway I can pass just a string to the deleteOrder. I want to pass order.key but also quotes around it.

Comment: Even so, you should attach the listener using Javascript rather than inline-HTML.

Comment: Thanks but how can I pass string with quotes. Also your code li.children[2] is not maintainable since it depends on the index of a children and this can change.

Comment: Thanks! but my question is still the same! How can I pass a string in template literal to a function with surrounding quotes.

Comment: What do you mean, string with quotes? `order` is an object, not a string. I guess if you wanted to turn it into a string you can use `JSON.stringify`, but I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Sorry. I mean order.key which is a string and I want to pass it to the deleteOrder function. Original code has been updated.

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for. Yes, it is ugly but at the same line I did not had to create li using append child and mix and match document.createElement with Template Literal. I updated the original question with the solution. Thanks!